# highlighting the button that fired an event

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

Consider a SilverLight project that has 31 hyperlinkbuttons. Those represent the days of the month. I'm using this code to highlight the hyperlinkbutton that respresent today's day.

```
var daynumberHyperButton = this.FindName("Day" + DateTime.Today.Day) as HyperlinkButton;

//Highlighting the day of the month
if (daynumberHyperButton != null)
{
   daynumberHyperButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Gray);
}
```

Then if I click on this highlighted hyperlinkbutton, it will open a childwindow to write some report.

```
private void dayHyperLink_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //This will initite and show the report window
    ReportWindow rapport = new ReportWindow();
    rapport.Closed += new EventHandler(rapport_Closed);
    rapport.Show();
}
```

When I close the childwindows by clicking the OK button, it changes the color of the hyperlinkbutton that was highlighted (todays day) because I'm using this code to do that:-

```
private void rapport_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReportWindow rapport = (ReportWindow)sender;
    var daynumberHyperButton = this.FindName("Day" + DateTime.Today.Day) as HyperlinkButton;
    if (rapport.UsersValue == "Röd" && rapport.DialogResult==true)
    {
        daynumberHyperButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }
    else if (rapport.UsersValue == "Gul")
    {
        daynumberHyperButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
    }
    else
    {
        daynumberHyperButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
    }
}
```

But if I click on any other hyperlinkbutton that is not highlighted, it still only change the color of the highlighted hyperlinkbutton. I know this because my `rapport_Closed` event has:

```
var daynumberHyperButton = this.FindName("Day" + DateTime.Today.Day) as HyperlinkButton;
```

How can I change the above code, which is part of my rapport_Closed event, so that it changes the color of the event firing (the one that opens the childwindow) hyperlinkbutton, no matter which hyperlinkbuttonis the one that fires the event?

Comment: I would be good to see your XAML code. You could keep track of the clicked link in the variable, so when windows closes you still have access to that variable to change its colour.

Comment: XAML code for the main page or the childwindow?

Comment: Please anyone that knows how to do my above question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok now i can say i've done it. Here is what i did if anyone have a similar problem.

1. In may Home.xaml.cs, i added a public property like this:-

   public HyperlinkButton dayHyperLink { get; set; }
2. To the Click event i added this code:-

   dayHyperLink = (HyperlinkButton)sender;
3. To the rapport_Closing event i changed the if statment to the code below:-

   if (rapport.UsersValue == "Röd" && rapport.DialogResult == true)
           {
               dayHyperLink.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
           }
   This made me feel happy ;)